# Why do I get a: This question doesn't meet our quality standards?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

- Why do I get a message

every time I try to create a question?

- Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to show some examples of the questions you tried to post

Answer (score 5):

This is answered in Meta

[What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-this-question-body-does-not-meet-our-quality-standar)

> #### What can I do to get the system to accept my question?
>
> Make sure your question has
>
> - a clear title
> - a reasonable explanation of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
> - correct use of English and actual sentences
> - proper spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation
> - If your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good
>   fit on our network.
>
> #### Can you be more specific?
>
> Exact details about the algorithm are not being released by the team.